# What is the way to export a Datatables with checkboxes in the different formats available (excel, csv, pdf...) in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, export-to-csv

I'm facing a problem concerning the CSV export of a DataTable when I want to select the rows with checkboxes.

The code to initialize a table :

```
function constructTableCustomers() {
var i;
// tableau datatable
var sHTML = "";
sHTML += '<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">';
sHTML += "<thead>";
sHTML += "<tr>";
sHTML += '<th style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="bulk_action_select_all" onclick="selectAllCustomers()"></th>';
sHTML += "<th>ID CLIENT </th>";
sHTML += "<th style='padding-right: 15px !important;'>EMAIL CLIENT</th>";
sHTML += "<th>ID PRODUIT</th>";
sHTML += "<th>NOM PRODUIT</th>";
sHTML += "<th>ATTRIBUT</th>";
sHTML += "<th>ID ATTRIBUT</th>";
sHTML += "<th>NOM</th>";
sHTML += "<th>PRENOM</th>";
sHTML += "<th>DATE DE CREATION</th>";
sHTML += "</tr>";
sHTML += "</thead>";
sHTML += "<tbody>";

// pour chaque ligne de résultat, construire la ligne dans datatable
for(i = 0; i < aOfCustomers.length; i++) {

    sHTML += '<tr style="text-align:center;">';

    sHTML += '<td>' + '<input type="checkbox" class="select-checkbox" id="checkbox_' + i + '">'  + '</td>';

    sHTML += `<td><a href='/${path_admin}/index.php/sell/customers/${aOfCustomers[i]["id_customer"]}/view?_token=${tokenAdminProducts}' target="_blank">${aOfCustomers[i]["id_customer"]}</a></td>`;

    sHTML += `<td><a href='/${path_admin}/index.php/sell/customers/${aOfCustomers[i]["id_customer"]}/view?_token=${tokenAdminProducts}' target="_blank">${aOfCustomers[i]["email"]}</a></td>`;
    
    sHTML += `<td><a href='/${path_admin}/index.php/sell/catalog/products/${aOfCustomers[i]["id_product"]}?_token=${tokenAdminProducts}' target='_blank'>${aOfCustomers[i]["id_product"]}</a></td>`; 
            
    sHTML += "<td>" + aOfCustomers[i]["product_name"] + "</td>";

    sHTML += "<td>" + aOfCustomers[i]["name"] + "</td>";

    sHTML += "<td>" + aOfCustomers[i]["id_product_attribute"] + "</td>";
    
    sHTML += "<td>" + aOfCustomers[i]["lastname"] + "</td>";

    sHTML += "<td>" + aOfCustomers[i]["firstname"] + "</td>";

    sHTML += "<td>" + aOfCustomers[i]["date_creation"] + "</td>";

    sHTML += '</tr>';
}
sHTML += "</tbody>";
sHTML += "</table>";
$('#customer_mail_alert_stock_table').html(sHTML);
}
```

here, the configuration for DataTable

```
const configuration = {
"stateSave": false,
"order": [[9, "desc"], [3, "asc"], [1, "asc"]],
"pageLength": 25,
"pagingType": "simple_numbers",
"searching": true,
"search" : {
    'search': product
},
"lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 250, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, 250, "Tous"]],

dom: 'Bflrtip',
buttons: [{ 
    extend: 'csvHtml5',
    text: 'CSV selected',
    exportOptions: {
        columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        modifier: {
            selected: true
        }
    }
}],
"retrieve": true,
"responsive": true,
"autoWidth": false
};
```

With this configuration, I try to export only the checked boxes of my table :

[my datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ovWm.png)

[exported file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kfgI.png)

Did you see the problem ?
the selection doesn't work

If you have any idea, please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: where can I use your advice in my code? 
I'm not sure I understood everything